# Remove files with unique basename?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I've a folder contains files like

```
a.JPG
a.GIF
b.JPG
c.JPG
c.GIF
d.GIF
```

The files `b.JPG` and `d.GIF` has only ONE occurrence in the basename part of their filename, so I want to remove `b.JPG` and `d.GIF`, how to do that in bash?

Answer (score 1):

This is a reasonable procedure:

1.- An unquoted * will list all files: loop over them.

2.- It is possible to remove the trailing extension with `${myfile%.*}`

3.- The expand the name with an asterisk `name.*` (dot to ensure end of name).

4.- And capture the result in an array: "tocount=( ... )"

5.- Finally, if the array count is 1, remove the file.

And the code:

```
for myfile in *; do
    tocount=( "${myfile%.*}".* )
    [[ ${#tocount[@]} -eq 1 ]] && rm "$myfile"
done
```

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for your edit. I am adding an useful dot to avoid files like `"c d.GIF"` and `"c.GIF"` being captured by the expansion of `"${myfile%.*}"*`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an associative array in bash version 4

```
declare -A count
# count each root-name
for f in *; do
    (( count["${f%.*}"] ++ ))
done
# delete the files with count 1
for key in "${!count[@]}"; do
    if (( ${count["$key"]} == 1 )); then
        rm "$key"*
    fi
done
```